# How to get Slim PHP Framework routes in a subdirectory on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, slim

I'm trying to move a Slim application to a subdirectory, so that it can be accessed at `example.com/api/`, but I'm having serious problems getting the routing to work.

The main script is at `/website/workbench/api/public/index.php`, so a call to `example.com/api/project/1` should hit the API folder. However, I also need to be able to access example.com's `index.html` file (which is running on Angular JS).

It does hit the PHP script when I go to `example.com/api/project/1` - I can `var_dump` variables and see them. However, the routing is not taking effect, and the request variables seem to be empty.

### /etc/nginx/sites-available/workbench

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

    root /website/workbench;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /api/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/public/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.appname=workbench";
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

(Obviously `example.com` is replaced with the real domain name)

### Partial output of `var_dump($_SERVER)`;

```
array(34) {
  ["USER"]=>
  string(8) "www-data"
  ["HOME"]=>
  string(8) "/var/www"
  ["FCGI_ROLE"]=>
  string(9) "RESPONDER"
  ["PHP_VALUE"]=>
  string(26) "newrelic.appname=workbench"
  ["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
  string(3) "GET"
  ["CONTENT_TYPE"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["CONTENT_LENGTH"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
  string(39) "/website/workbench/api/public/index.php"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(21) "/api/public/index.php"
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(15) "/api/projects/1"
  ["DOCUMENT_URI"]=>
  string(21) "/api/public/index.php"
  ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
  string(18) "/website/workbench"
  ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
  string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
  ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=>
  string(7) "CGI/1.1"
  ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=>
  string(11) "nginx/1.4.6"
}
```

`var_dump($_REQUEST)` gives an empty array.

Clearly there's something spectacularly wrong with my set-up, but I'm struggling to see what! Changing `$query_string` to `$args` has no effect either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can remove `$query_string` from `try_files`. Add a `root` directive in `/api` location, like this:

```
location /api {
    root /website/workbench/api;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.php;
}
```

and use the `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` parameter eventually defined as:

```
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

into the `fastcgi_params` file.

Comment: Thanks for this. Slim will pick up the parameters from request_uri, but this always gets prepended with api/. I also needed to move the root parameter so it's in each location block. I'm told this is bad practice, but it has to be done because the fastcgi location block relies on it.

Comment: Will be any side effect with Slim Framework routing maintaining `$query_string` in the `try_files` line?

Answer (score 10):

Very late to the party here, but I was having the same issue with serving static files (an Angular application) in the root of the site, and serving a slim application in /api. As you pointed out, Slim really needs the `REQUEST_URI` to *not* have the `/api` in it.

```
server {
 server_name example.com;

    location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
           alias /path/to/slim-app/public/;
           try_files $1 $1/ @php;
           index index.php;
    }

    location / {
            root /path/to/your/static/files;
    }

    location @php {
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/api)(/.*)$;
           fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           include fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/slim-app/public/index.php;
           fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $fastcgi_path_info;
           fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
    }
 }
```

The key for me lied in the `fastcgi_split_path_info` trickery. As per http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_split_path_info, what the operation does is split the `$fastcgi_path_info` variable into two *new* variables called `$fastcgi_script_name` and `$fastcgi_path_info`.

When you put in `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/api)(/.*)$;` you essentially set `$fastcgi_script_name` to `/api` and set `$fastcgi_path_info` to `/my/route`. I found this was enough to get Slim (v3) working the way I wanted.

However, I also found that my default Slim app has `DOCUMENT_URL` and `SCRIPT_NAME` variables set to `index.php`. So you can also set them (although it doesn't *seem* to be required):

```
set $script_name "/index.php";
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $script_name;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $script_name;
```

Comment: After an hour of trying my own ideas and different suggestions, this one worked perfectly.